# How is it possible to "sed" through a port?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, port, sed, sockets

For example:
The telnet daemon server is echoing "Hello there user."
For the sake of the example, say the version of the daemon cannot be changed at the moment and we have to make a better greeting.

the client connects like this:

```
 telnet 127.0.0.1 1111
 >Hello there user.
```

it would be easy to sed through the client, of course...

```
 telnet 127.0.0.1 1111 | sed 's/user/Dear user/g'
 >Hello there Dear user.
```

But this is unwanted. we'd like the client to keep connecting normally.

Is it possible to sed directly on the daemon port 1111 to output the altered greeting somehow? and how?

Comment: You can use two instances of netcat. But it would be a lot easier to just edit the demon binary in a hex editor...

Comment: For sure, agreed for this example but the question regarded a sed-like operation on the socket, so that a stream would be modified. Not just a static message by the server. In this case hex editing would not do

Comment: What's up Ted.... I see that you said, that you wanna use Sed. Did you pull that idea right off the top of your head, or did you learn it from that same book that I read?  I'll check in later to see if your needs ever got fed just before I tuck my wife in to bed.

Comment: I don't think I read the book you did, would be great if you did succeed